Shared memory sizing for a numpy array
In the example seen on superfastpython.com, the size of a shared memory segment to be used to support a 1-dimensional numpy array is calculated as the number of elements multiplied by the data type size.
We know that the size parameter given to the SharedMemory constructor is a minimum. Thus, in many cases, the actual size may be larger than that specified - and that's fine.
But what if the specified size is an exact multiple of the underlying memory page size?
Consider this:
import numpy as np
from multiprocessing.shared_memory import SharedMemory

n = 2048
s = n * np.dtype(np.double).itemsize
shm = SharedMemory(create=True, size=s)
try:
    assert s == shm.size
    a = np.ndarray((n,), dtype=np.double, buffer=shm.buf)
    a.fill(0.0)
finally:
    shm.close()
    shm.unlink()

In this case (Python 13.3.0 on macOS 15.0.1) the value of s is 16,384 which happens to be a precise multiple of the underlying page size and therefore shm.size is equal to s
Maybe I don't know enough about numpy but I would have imagined that the ndarray would need more space for internal / management structures.
Can someone please explain why this works and why there's no apparent need to allow extra space in the shared memory segment?

An array does have a bunch of metadata that takes a bunch of extra space, but that metadata is stored separately from its data buffer. The shared memory you're allocating is just for the data buffer.

Apologies. I re-read your answer and reviewed my code. It makes sense now. Thank you
